# Accessing object keys with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, multidimensional-array

I have some chess pieces stored as an array of objects and I want to access the keys using for loop, but I receive an error message of "Cannot read property '0' of undefined." Why is this occurring?

Thanks for any help!

Javascript:

```
pawn = {
    color: [
              {c1: 'white'}, {c2: 'white'}, {c3: 'white'}, {c4: 'white'}, {c5: 'white'}, {c6: 'white'},
              {c7: 'white'}, {c8: 'white'}, {c9: 'black'}, {c10:'black'}, {c11: 'black'}, {c12: 'black'},
              {c13:'black'}, {c14:'black'}, {c15:'black'}, {c16:'black'}
           ],
   playable: function()
   {        
        k1 = [];
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            k1.push(Object.keys(pawn.color[i]));
            console.log(k1);    //[['c1'], ['c2'], ['c3'], ['c4'], ['c5'], ['c6'], ['c7'], ['c8'], 
                          // ['c9'], ['c10'], ['c11'], ['c12'], ['c13'], ['c14'], ['c15'], ['c16']];
        }

        for (piece = 0; piece < 16; piece++)
            {
                if (pawn.color[piece].k1[piece][0] == 'white'){ //error msg.
                    console.log('white');
                }

                if (pawn.color[piece].k1[piece][0] == 'black'){ //error msg.
                    console.log('black');
                }
            }
   };
```

Comment: `pawn.color[piece].k1` -- `color` array object has no `k1` property.

Comment: change this `pawn.color[piece].k1[piece][0]` to this `pawn.color[piece][k1[piece]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `color` array has 16 entries. Each of those entries is an object of the form:

```
{ key: color }
```

where `key` is "c1" through "c16" and `color` is either "black" or "white".

In your for-loop, you try this:

```
if (pawn.color[piece].k1[piece][0] == 'white'){
```

Let's break that down:

- pawn.color[piece] - this gives an object like `{c1: 'white'}`
- pawn.color[piece].k1 - this gives `undefined` because the object doesn't have a `k1` value.
- pawn.color[piece].k1[piece] - gives TypeError because you tried to access `undefined`

What you probably wanted is this:

```
if (pawn.color[piece][k1[piece][0]] == 'white') {
```

but it's easier to read if you split it out a bit like this:

```
const firstKey = k1[piece][0];
if (pawn.color[piece][firstKey] == 'white') {
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimmes it can be tricky to figure out how to access arrays with objects.  Check the syntax and let me know if you don't understand.

```js
pawn = {
    color: [
              {c1: 'white'}, {c2: 'white'}, {c3: 'white'}, {c4: 'white'}, {c5: 'white'}, {c6: 'white'},
              {c7: 'white'}, {c8: 'white'}, {c9: 'black'}, {c10:'black'}, {c11: 'black'}, {c12: 'black'},
              {c13:'black'}, {c14:'black'}, {c15:'black'}, {c16:'black'}
           ]};
   function payable()
   {        
        k1 = [];
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            k1.push(Object.keys(pawn.color[i]));
           // console.log(k1);    //[['c1'], ['c2'], ['c3'], ['c4'], ['c5'], ['c6'], ['c7'], ['c8'], 
                          // ['c9'], ['c10'], ['c11'], ['c12'], ['c13'], ['c14'], ['c15'], ['c16']];
        }  
        
   

        for (piece = 0; piece < 16; piece++)
            {          
            
                if (pawn.color[piece][k1[piece][0]] == 'white'){ //error msg.
                    console.log('white');
                }

                if (pawn.color[piece][k1[piece][0]] == 'black'){ //error msg.
                    console.log('black');
                }
            }
   };
   
   payable();
```